# Keyword search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search-engine

I'm developing an android application where the user needs to key in a string/sentence of strings as a keyword(s) and based on that input, some string should be retrieved from a database. I am looking for a suitable algorithm for this purpose. I have gone through many answers and many algorithms such as tfidf and Boyer-Moore but I am still confused of choosing the most efficient algorithm. Anyone has a suggestion? 
(the purpose is to retrieve some string based on entered keywords)

Thanks

Comment: If the question is unclear, please let me know !

Answer (score 0):

I wrote autocomplete search (by phrases/subphrases), you can see 
performance and dictionaries size on my demo:

http://olegh.ftp.sh/autocomplete.html

This is Celeron-300 machine, FreeBSD OS. And loadin less than 1% CPU during active search.
But, written on C++, and uses mmap/pread system calls. So, I not sure, will it works on Android. I can share sources upon request.

Regarding algorithm: Used preindexed hash-index file, 
based on all possible prefixes from phrases from dictionary. 
By mmapped hash-table found bucket, which fetch into memory by pread.

Indexing relatively slow operation: 
indexing of 15,000,000 dictionary entries can consume ~1hour on PERL script.
But search/retrieve extremely quick, and performance is not dependent on dictionary size.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend writing your own algorithm; rather, you should use an existing library like [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/).